# How to increase speed of algorithm performance for calculation minimal number of moves?

Tags: algorithm, performance, python-3.x, loops, cycle

I participate codefights and have the task find the minimal number of moves that are required to obtain a strictly increasing sequence from the input. As an input there are arrays of integers and accourding to the rule I can increase exactly one element an array by one per one move.

```
inputArray: [1, 1, 1]
Expected Output:3

inputArray: [-1000, 0, -2, 0]
Expected Output:5

inputArray: [2, 1, 10, 1]
Expected Output:12

inputArray: [2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 12, 12, 10, 15]
Expected Output:13
```

There are also conditions for input and output:

```
[time limit] 4000ms (py3)
[input] array.integer inputArray
3 ≤ inputArray.length ≤ 105,
-105 ≤ inputArray[i] ≤ 105
[output] integer
```

I came up with the followitn solution:

```
def arrayChange(inputArray):
k=0
for i in range(len(inputArray)-1):
    if (inputArray[i]<inputArray[i+1]) == False:
        while inputArray[i+1]<=inputArray[i]:
            inputArray[i+1] = inputArray[i+1] + 1
            k +=1
return k
```

However, apperantly for some tests that I cannot observe my algorithm performance is out of the time limits:

> 6/8
>   Execution time limit exceeded on test 7: Program exceeded the execution time limit. Make sure that it completes execution in a few seconds for any possible input.
>   Sample tests: 4/4
>   Hidden tests: 2/4

How to improve my algorithm for increasing performance speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you increase by 1 at a time. Currently you have this code snippet:

`inputArray[i+1] = inputArray[i+1] + 1`

Instead of incrementing by 1 each time, why not add all of the numbers at once? For example, if you have the list `[1, 3, 0]` it makes sense to add 4 to the last element. Doing this would go much more quickly than adding 1 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

@fileyfood500 gave me a very usefull hint and here is my solution that works:

```
deltX=0
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if (a[i]<a[i+1]) == False:
        deltX1 = abs(a[i+1]-a[i])+1
        a[i+1] = a[i+1] + deltX1
        deltX += deltX1
print(deltX)
```

Now I do not need while loop at all because I increase the item, that should be increased by necessary number in one step.

Answer (score 1):

```
def arrayChange(inputArray):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1,len(inputArray)):
        while inputArray[i] <= inputArray[i-1]:
            c = inputArray[i]
            inputArray[i]= inputArray[i-1]+1
            count += inputArray[i] - c 
    return count
```

This way you increment it directly and the time will be less.
Then just subtract the new value from the earlier one to get the number of times it increments.